# Servoy - Getting all data from db table to display as list

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql

I am relatively new to Servoy and Javascript so that might be why i can't get this to work but here goes:

I am trying to get a label to display all of the data from a specific column from my database table in a list.

I tried to add a dataProvider but that adds only one record per  page.

I need the items to be listed below each other so it makes it easier for me to see.

I have also tried adding:

```
function firstName(){
    foundset.loadAllRecords();
    return;
}
```

and setting it as an onRender to see if that displays everything

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for the answer then here it is:

Use a label and set the text of the label to

```
%%list_display%%
```

Set your form layout to Tableview

The answer for above was using Servoy Developer and PostgresSQl